# Does CUM EŌ EO mean I go with them?

Tags: translation-check, pronunciation

If so, the pronunciation of the long vowel Ō is really important?

Comment: Where is this from? And which part are you curious about in particular?

Comment: Just curious if the sentence makes sense. I am currently studying the personal nouns and this one came up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, no. *eo* is singular, so it would be "with him" or "with it." If you wanted to make it plural, it would be *cum eīs eō.*

Also, the final -o on present verbs is long (although sometimes it'll be shortened in poetry, I believe). It's not always marked in dictionaries because it's a standard rule, i.e. it's part of the grammar, not the individual word, so there's no need to mark it. You memorize the rule and you know it for all verbs. That makes the sentence *cum eō eō*, and the two words are homophones.

Speaking of ambiguity, without context, it could also mean "when in that place I am going."

Comment: Ahh, sorry. It would be CUM EIS EO? Thank you.

Comment: @JohhanSantana I updated the answer for you.

Comment: I can count at least four substantially different translations: two full sentences ('with him I go', 'when I go, I go') and two partial ('when thither I go', 'when therefore I go').